# Simple python regex, match after colon

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple regex question that's driving me crazy.
I have a variable `x = "field1: XXXX field2: YYYY"`.
I want to retrieve `YYYY` (note that this is an example value).
My approach was as follows:

```
values = re.match('field2:\s(.*)', x)
print values.groups()
```

It's not matching anything. Can I get some help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your regex is good

```
field2:\s(.*)
```

Try this code

```
match = re.search(r"field2:\s(.*)", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

Answer (score 9):

[`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.matchv) only matches at the start of the string. You want to use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

Also, you should use a verbatim string:

```
>>> values = re.search(r'field2:\s(.*)', x)
>>> print values.groups()
('YYYY',)
```